# How do I get the statistics of an app from google play

Tags: google-play

I want to get the statistics of any particular app from the Google Play. After authentication, I'll provide a URL and the the corresponding stats of that app will start downloading. There is a ZIP folder with CSV files that'll be downloaded.

What I've done is:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data = array(
    'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
    'Email'       => my mail address@gmail.com,
    'Passwd'      => my password for this account,
    'source'      => the name of that particular app,
    'service'     => 'writely'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$hasil = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is for authentication. After this, I want to download the statistics:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://play.google.com/apps/publish/statistics/download?package=[my apps name]&sd=[starting date]&ed=[ending date]&dim=[dimensional data]&met=[metrics data]&dev_acc=[developer account ID]");

$header[] = 'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $hasil;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
```

After starting the script, the download should automatically start.

Comment: Thanks @jterry, actually I don't have much idea about it.